# .net SerialPort closes after a minute on tablet

Tags: serial-port, tablet

I am running my app on an Intel Atom processor.  There are no issues on my PC, just the tablet.

```
Application.Run(new MyApp());

public MyApp()
{
  ...
  SerialPort port = new SerialPort(...)
  port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
  port.Open();
}
```

When I run my app on my PC, there are no issues, and I can send serial data over for as long as I'd like.  However when I run it on my tablet, after about a minute from launching, the serial port is closed and no longer reading.  I'm not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Tablet machines like to power down devices to save battery power.  If you can't find the configuration setting that controls that in device manager then ask at superuser.com

Comment: I played around with the power options, which did not change the behavior of this issue.